# Using IUP with Lua on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, lua, installation, iup

I'm trying to get IUP working on Ubuntu.  I downloaded the binaries from sourceforge and the libraries seem to be in place in /usr/lib/libiup*.so, but when I write a script like the following:

```
require("iuplua")
iup.Message('Testing App!', 'Finished Successfully!')
```

I get an error:

```
lua: attempt to call a nil value
stack traceback:
    [C]: ?
    [C]: in function 'require'
    test.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

Looking into it, I saw a message noting that someone seemed to have fixed it - their "LD_LIBRARY_PATH did not point to the right cd and im directories" or something similar.  I couldn't seem to correct my problem w the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.  I saw another note from 2008 saying that the "IUPLua binaries have hardcoded lua bytecode that is causing the error".  I tried to compile from the sources, but I'm getting errors related to cd.h.

Any help would be -greatly- appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the IUP-Users mailing list: https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/iup-users

Comment: What do you get when you run `for k,v in pairs(iup) do print(k,v) end`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is something you can check out, perhaps it will help.

When you load a module with **require** Lua uses the package paths to determine where to look for the module.

> package.path: Where Lua looks for .lua modules
>   package.cpath: Where Lua looks for .so/.dll modules

Have a look at this section of the Lua manual: [Modules](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.3). Specifically, the section on **package.path** and **package.cpath**.

You can check what the current paths are like:

```
print(package.path.."\n"..package.cpath)
```

You can append the paths like:

```
package.path = package.path..";/usr/lib/?.lua"
package.cpath = package.cpath..";/usr/lib/?.so"
```